# problem to run my project in windows phone 7.1 update

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I was trying some code for push notification(which has sender windows phone client and wcf service) in windows phone 7.0.

I then install windows phone 7.1 beta update

and run the same code

but i m getting

"Connection failed because of invalid command-line arguments." 
error.

I want to know how to solve this issue......

Comment: It'd be really handy if you included code in your question so we can see what you are trying.

Comment: get the code from this link http://chris.59north.com/post/Using-Windows-Phone-7-Push-Notifications.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have either have a misconfigured project or a failed installation of the updated SDK.

Your first choice would be creating a new WP7 application that targets 7.0 systems (if still needed). See if you can launch it through the emulator (which I am assuming is the issue). Try reloading the same project again.

In the most extreme case, remove everything WP7 dev-related and re-install the dev tools.